# Writing the same file 15 times per second fails sometimes after 50 writes. How to solve?

Tags: windows, file

I have a Windows application that continuously writes the same file over an over again.  About 15 times per second, the following happens:

- Open file X for writing
- Add some text to file X
- Close file X
- Copy file X to folder Y
- Delete file X

(it's a bit complex to explain why this is done this way)

If I do this on my own system, this works perfectly and never fails.
Also at most of my customers this works perfectly.

However, at one of my customers, opening the file for writing fails after a few seconds (after about 50 times the file is opened,closed,...).

Can file-caching in Windows keep a file locked for a longer time?
Or is the deletion of the file not guaranteed to be executed immediately?
Of is there some kind of limit of Windows I run into?

Any suggestions?

Comment: The deletion of the file is not guaranteed to be executed immediately.  Typically this happens because anti-virus software is holding it open.

Comment: Harry, do you have a reference to a technical article where I can find more information about this claim?

Comment: The [documentation for the DeleteFile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "The DeleteFile function marks a file for deletion on close. Therefore, the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is closed. Subsequent calls to CreateFile to open the file fail with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED."

Comment: Harry, thanks.  If indeed a virus scanner is involved, the virus scanner might still have the file open.  Thanks.